# Strange behavior of StringReplace, same expression evaluated differently

Tags: string-manipulation

I have two expressions which are exactly same:

```
StringReplace["in the next few days", {"in" -> "ffdsf"}]
```

and

```
StringReplace["in the next few days", {"in­" -> "ffdsf"}]
```

However,the first one evaluated to "ffdsf the next few days" while the second one remained "in the next few days"

By `Trace` I have

```
StringReplace["in the next few days", {"in" -> "ffdsf"}] // Trace

{{{\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\"\<in\>\"", "->", "\"\<ffdsf\>\""}],
HoldForm]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\"\<in\>\"", "->", "\"\<ffdsf\>\""}],
HoldForm]\)}, \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"\"\<in\>\"", "->", "\"\<ffdsf\>\""}], "}"}],
HoldForm]\)}, \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"StringReplace", "[", 
RowBox[{"\"\<in the next few days\>\"", ",", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"\"\<in\>\"", "->", "\"\<ffdsf\>\""}], "}"}]}], "]"}],
HoldForm]\), \!\(\*
TagBox["\"\<ffdsf the next few days\>\"",
HoldForm]\)}
```

and

```
StringReplace["in the next few days", {"in­" -> "ffdsf"}] // Trace

{{{\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\<\"in­\"\>", "->", "\<\"ffdsf\"\>"}],
HoldForm]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\<\"in­\"\>", "->", "\<\"ffdsf\"\>"}],
HoldForm]\)}, \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"\<\"in­\"\>", "->", "\<\"ffdsf\"\>"}], "}"}],
HoldForm]\)}, \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"StringReplace", "[", 
RowBox[{"\<\"in the next few days\"\>", ",", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"\<\"in­\"\>", "->", "\<\"ffdsf\"\>"}], "}"}]}], "]"}],
HoldForm]\), \!\(\*
TagBox["\<\"in the next few days\"\>",
HoldForm]\)}
```

What happened? Why the second StringReplace didn't evaluate?

I'm using Mathematica10.0.2 on windows7, the problem remains after restarting Mathematica. copy this  `StringReplace["in the next few days", {"in" -> "ffdsf"}]` and this `StringReplace["in the next few days", {"in­" -> "ffdsf"}]` from this website to notebook and then they would evaluate differently.

after open the notebook by Notepad++, I found the clue. The abnormal expression, the one didn't evaluate, looks like

```
Cell[CellGroupData[{
Cell[BoxData[
RowBox[{"StringReplace", "[", 
RowBox[{"\"\<in the next few days\>\"", ",", " ", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
"\"\<in\[DiscretionaryHyphen]\>\"", " ", "->", " ", "\"\<ffdsf\>\""}], 
"}"}]}], "]"}]], "Input"],

Cell[BoxData["\<\"in the next few days\"\>"], "Output",
CellChangeTimes->{3.676188472550608*^9}]
}, Open  ]]
```

in Notepad++, while the normal expression, looks like

```
Cell[CellGroupData[{

Cell[BoxData[
RowBox[{"StringReplace", "[", 
RowBox[{"\"\<in the next few days\>\"", ",", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"\"\<in\>\"", "\[Rule]", "\"\<ffdsf\>\""}], "}"}]}], 
"]"}]], "Input"],

Cell[BoxData["\<\"ffdsf the next few days\"\>"], "Output",
CellChangeTimes->{3.676188474586664*^9}]
}, Open  ]]
```

copy the above two Cells into notebook then they looks exactly same(in the mathematica notebook), while the first one didn't evaluated correctly.

Comment: With questions like this, you *must* give complete information to reproduce the problem, including: 1. is this evaluated after a kernel restart?  Try to give complete instructions to reproduce it. 2. what version of Mathematica, including release number? 3. what OS?

Comment: I cannot reproduce in 9.0.1, 10.0.2, 10.3.1 or 10.4.1 on OS X.

Comment: I do not reproduce with versions 5.2, 8.0.4 and 10.4.1 on Win7 x64.

Comment: do not type expression in notebook, copy them  respectively from this website. @Szabolcs

Comment: You twice say "from this website".  This website is a huge collection of code.  Do you think you could be a little more explicit about *where* on this website?

Comment: @EricTowers here: `StringReplace["in the next few days", {"in­" -> "ffdsf"}]`

Comment: @Harry : Are you just irrationally opposed to indicating which page has these hidden characters *so it can be fixed*?

Comment: It has been fixed and I didn't realize that there is a hidden character until someone pointed it out. How could I know which page  these hidden characters exist? They are hidden. @EricTowers

Comment: You comments taken together mean: "I have randomly and unknowingly copied text from some unknown page somewhere on a website of several hundred thousand pages."  This would at lease make defensible that at no time did you indicate from where the text came.  Even when asked.  Repeatedly.  Otherwise, you have been needlessly vague.

Comment: Oh..I see, you mean the original source webpage where I got this "in the next few days"? I got it from http://broadskyblog.blogspot.com/ (search for "in the next few…+NOUN" in the page). Strangely, the string on that website was normal. When I copyed the list into txt file and Imported by mathematica, the hidden character appeared.

Comment: @EricTowers see my new question  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119862/import-create-evil-invisible-characters-when-import-txt-including-ellipsis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the second line, the string that looks like `"in"` is in fact a three-character string.  The third character is a [soft-hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen): it is invisible and it is used to mark a position where a word can be hyphenated.  It has character code 173.

`StringReplace` finds no match due to this invisible third character.

You can detect this using [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) or [`ToCharacterCode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToCharacterCode.html).

[image]

Comment: I will kill the one who invented this damn character...are they any similar invisible characters?

Comment: This problem is just like those involving stupid Boxes in a normal expression. extremely hard to detect......

Comment: @Harry Yes, there are a few. I love this one because it lets me have properly justified ebooks with good hyphenation ;-)  Another one is the zero width space.  Some more mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters  There are also characters which look the same, yet they are different.  An example is space vs non-breaking space.  Another one is capital Roman A vs capital Greek Alpha, Α.